# Trying to perform two different functionality on button click which is in jQuery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am doing project in MVC 4. And I'm using  dialog boxes to perform operations. I am using Views and partial views for accomplishing my task.

> What I meant by trying to perform two operation is I want to call a
>   action method which will save existing data in database and also close
>   the dialog box properly and same for the add functionality i.e. add
>   new row in database and close the dialog box properly.

Right now what happening is

1. I can **successfully** edit record and save it in database. 
   But once I click on Create New link it
   **displays records which were entered in edit pop up**.
2. If I click on create new link for the first time I get the pop up for save and once I click on save button it dooes not get save in database.

In short

> I am not able to call close method of dialog and action method in my
>   controller both at the same time

I will post code for everything that I have done till now.

**CurrentLocation View**

```
@model PITCRoster.RosterManagementEntities

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CurrentLocation";
}

<script src="~/Content/PopUp.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<h2>CurrentLocation</h2>
@*<input type="button" value="List All Current Locations" onclick="Display('DisplayCurrentLocation')" />*@
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_DisplayCurrentLocation", Model.tblCurrentLocations);
}

<div id="dialog">
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddLocation", "Lookups", FormMethod.Post))
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_AddLocation", new PITCRoster.tblCurrentLocation());
}
</div>
```

This view when rendered shows list of all the location that are in database including links to `create new location` , `edit` and `delete` location.

Depending on that I render partial views for them.

**_AddLocation** partial view is rendered and in jQuery(which I will post next)
I have set **autoOpen** of **dialog** to **false**.

Follwing is code for partial views.

**_DisplayCurrentLocation Partial View**

```
   @model IEnumerable<PITCRoster.tblCurrentLocation>

<p>
    <a href="#" class="create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LocationId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="edit" data-url="@Url.Action("EditLocation", "Lookups", new { id=item.LocationId})">Edit</a>

                @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteLocation", "Lookups", new { id = @item.LocationId }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class="deleteForm"}))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                }

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**_AddLocation Partial View**

```
@model PITCRoster.tblCurrentLocation

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>tblCurrentLocation</legend>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

**_EditLocation Partial View**

```
    @model PITCRoster.tblCurrentLocation

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveLocation", "Lookups", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "saveForm" }))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>tblCurrentLocation</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LocationId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocationId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

**Now I will post my Action Methods in controller**

**return CurrentLocation view**

```
  public ActionResult CurrentLocation()
        {
            return View(rosterManagementEntities);
        }
```

**Add Location**

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddLocation(tblCurrentLocation tblCurrentLocation)
    {
        unitOfWork.tblCurrentLocation.Insert(tblCurrentLocation);
        unitOfWork.Save();
        return View("CurrentLocation", rosterManagementEntities);
    }

**Edit Location**

```
public ActionResult EditLocation(string id)
        {
            int locationId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            tblCurrentLocation tblCurrentLocation = unitOfWork.tblCurrentLocation.GetByID(locationId);
            return PartialView("_EditLocation", tblCurrentLocation);
        }
```

**Save Location**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveLocation(tblCurrentLocation tblCurrentLocation)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
        unitOfWork.tblCurrentLocation.Update(tblCurrentLocation);
        unitOfWork.Save();
        return View("CurrentLocation", rosterManagementEntities);
    }
```

**Delete**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteLocation(int id)
    {
        unitOfWork.tblCurrentLocation.Delete(id);
        unitOfWork.Save();
        return View("CurrentLocation", rosterManagementEntities);
    }
```

I will post my script for dialog

When a user clicks on edit link it it will send a url with unique ID and in **jQuery** `$.get()` will retrieve that data and display dialog as follows

```
 $('.edit').click(function () {
        $.get($(this).data('url'), function (data) {
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                bgiframe: true,
                width: 800,
                height: 250,
                open: function () {

                    document.getElementById('dialog').innerHTML = data;
                },
                close: function () {
                    debugger;
                    document.getElementById('dialog').innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById('dialog').innerText = "";
                    $("#dialog").empty().dialog("destroy");

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

When form is **loaded** it will create one dialog and set it's **autoOpen** to **false** 
and when user clicks on create new link it will just open that dialog 
This is for Creating new location

```
   $(".create").click(function CreateNewUser() {
        debugger;
        try {

            $("#dialog").dialog('open');
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    });

$("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        bgiframe: true,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,

        close: function () {
            debugger;
            document.getElementById('dialog').innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById('dialog').innerText = "";
            $("#dialog").empty().dialog("destroy");
            window.location.reload();
        }


    });
```

So I will state my problem again

My code either performs destroy the dialog operation or saves the data in the database; but not both.

> I am not able to call **close** method of dialog and **action method** in my
>   controller both at the same time

What code should I change to do both the tasks?

I have a hunch that **Ajax** should be used... But how?

Please help...

Sorry for the long post...

Thank you for being patience.. :)

Comment: Is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/) the sort of functionality your looking for?

Comment: Yes.. but how can I call action method in my controller as well do the necessary task to hide/destroy the dialog...

Comment: You just handle the buttons in your form - but why on earth are you destroying the dialog and doing a refresh each time? When you want to edit a row, just set the form values to the values that are in the row, and when you want to add a new row, reset the form. In the ajax callback, if successfull, update the values in the corresponding row. That way you also get client side validation and far better performance

Comment: Okay I will try it, thanks mate :-)

Comment: Hey @StephenMuecke I tried your code.. It works as per my requirement...
But I couldn't glue your code with mine...
Can you please help me with where should I change my code with yours to make it work?

Comment: No worries!! Finally succeeded :)